# Visual Basic declaration question

Tags: vb.net, dao

I'm attempting to declare DAO variables in VB, but when I go to assignment statements, it says they must be declared. But I've just declared them in the line above! What's going on?

Code:

> ```
>  Public Class frmBaseForm
>
>      Public acDb As dao.Database
>      Public acRs As dao.Recordset
>
>      acRs = acDb.OpenRecordset("Something")
>
>  End Class
> ```

acRs shows up as undeclared in the last line.

Comment: which version of vb?  I'm assuming 6 or vba, but part of me is nagging that it might be vb.net.  If it is the latter, you shouldn't even be using dao objects at all.

Comment: I'm programming in VB 2008 Express Edition IDE from Microsoft. So, whichever version of VB that uses. What should I be using instead of dao? I need to manipulate Access databases and send them to Powerpoint.

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Class frmBaseForm

    Public acDb As dao.Database
    Public acRs As dao.Recordset

   Public Sub ArbitraryEvent()
    acDB = New dao.Database
    acRs = acDb.OpenRecordset("Something")
   End Sub
End Class
```

Or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You must first add the Dao object library in your project(that's just in case you haven't done so yet).